# Word for the song, that we hum or sing all day, once we listen it

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

We listen to songs, and sometimes we forget them because they are boring.

And when we listen to a catchy song, we hum it or sing it whole the day. Is it okay to consider such songs as memorable? If not, is there any specific word for this?

Comment: The word I think you're looking for is "catchy" A catchy song is one whose melody is very easy to remember and to reproduce.  P.S I think you meant to say *when we listen to* ***catchy songs*** Not *we catchy songs*

Comment: Do you want the word for a song that doesn't leave your head, as soon as you hear it? IOW the tune keeps playing in your head. There's a word for that too.

Comment: The adjective *haunting* can be used.

Comment: The question that is marked as already answered does not have as good an answer as the one here. There are no references and some dubious answers there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We call it an **[earworm](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/earworm)**.

> A catchy song or tune that runs continually through a person's mind.

Comment: Please cite your source, include the name of the dictionary in the actual answer, not in a comment. Please do not say "Google" the company usually takes dictionary definitions from Oxford Dictionaries. Thanks.

Comment: It's a small world after all, it's a small world after all, it's a small world after all, it's a small, small world!